# How I create dialog only for (e.g) 5sn?

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to creeate `dialog` for temporary time(*Say After Few Seconds It should get cancelled Automatically*).

I create dialog with this code :

```
Dialog    dl=new Dialog(myclass.this);
            dl.setTitle("HELLE WORLD");
            dl.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            dl.show();
```

And I finish dialog with this : `dl.cancel();`

But when write this ? (for example I finish dialog 5 sn after.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok create a dialog as usual and start a countdown timer of say 5 sec, as the countdown timer expires in `onFinish` use `dialog.dismiss()`  to stop it after certain time.

Like this,

```
    new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

For More Detail Go to [This Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you use `Handler` and `postDelayed`

Like this,

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dl.cancel();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Toast for this purpose, you can customize toast too.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello toast", 2000);
```

This instrction will show a message on screen for duration 2 secs. To learn more about toast see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

But if you still insist to use Dialog, set a timer on this dialog, and on timeout dismiss the dialog.

Comment: please give me code example ? I try something but it is not working.